Cannot use JavaScriptExecutor in HtmlUnit-Android Package
I cannot seem to find anything which lets me progress from this stumbling block, as there doesn't appear to be an 'execute' in JavaScriptExecutor.  All suggestions as how I might overcome this gratefully received:
Snippet in Kotlin not Java (sorry):
import org.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutor
import org.htmlunit.WebClient
import org.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor
import org.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
    
private lateinit var mainScreen : HtmlPage

var webClient = WebClient()     // Create the webClient

var mainPage = webClient.getPage(anyURL) as HtmlPage        // Retrieve a target page

var jsexecutor: JavaScriptExecutor = webClient as JavaScriptExecutor    // Declare a JS executor
        
var buttonsList = mainPage.getElementsByTagName("button") as List<HtmlButton> // Find all the buttons
for (targetButton in buttonsList )   // Loop round the buttons
{
    if (targetButton.textContent == "Continue") // This is the one I'm looking for
    {
        jsexecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", targetButton) // No 'executeScript'!! =:-{
    }
}

and in app:build.gradle.kts  I have this defined:
implementation(group="org.htmlunit", name="htmlunit3-android", version="4.3.0")

Thanks again for any help

Why not simply calling click() on the button?
And maybe the script from the button executes async (e.g. by using a timer). In this case you have to wait a bit...
If you still have problems please open an issue for htmlunit-android and i will try to provide more details - but therefor i need the url you like to access.

Thanks for the interest and the suggestion ... but I already tried a normal 'click()'  The problem is, the webpage doesn't have any kind of submit or action or any kind of javascript associated with the button (or any href or anything). When I use Selenium in a .Net version, 'click()' also doesn't work ... but 'executeScript' does (!!) so I was trying a similar approach with htnlunit-android.  I'll open the issue for htmlunit-android and suppy the url there.  Thanks again, most kind
